# htaccess 500 error when rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-error

My htaccess currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Lesson/Add/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ ./AddLesson.php?type=$1&data=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Lesson/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ ./Lesson.php?type=$1&data=$2 [NC,L]
```

I have the rules ordered so the if the url was `foo.com/lesson/add/` then the first rule is matched, but this results in a 500 server error when I navigate to `foo.com/lesson/`.

However, if I remove the question mark on the lesson line `RewriteRule ^Lesson/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ ./Lesson.php?type=$1&data=$2 [NC,L]` it works.

I need the final slash to be optional.

Comment: Those `?` in the rules are strange. And also the `./` in the rules targets appear unfamiliar.

Comment: The `?` are to make the slashes optional and the `./` in the targets are because the `.htaccess` file is in a subfolder of the domain. I guess it is the way I have structured my site.

Comment: Nope. Indeed the `?` is the "optional" operator, but the way you use it does make no sense. Especially with slashes (`/`) being optional, whilst stuff in between is not. And there is not reason to use `./` inside a rewrite rule, withing .htaccess or not. You can just leave it away.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this regex:

```
 ^Lesson/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$
```

Which is causing infinite looping and causing 500 error since it matches `/lesson/` as well as `/Lesson.php`. Change 2nd rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^Lesson/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ ./Lesson.php?type=$1&data=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```